# Active Directory delegation in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, delegation

I'm trying to delegate permissions 'Create all child objects' and 'Delete all child objects' on 'All descendant object'. When giving the permissions in GUI, the ACL looks like this:

```
ActiveDirectoryRights : CreateChild, DeleteChild
InheritanceType : All
ObjectType : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
InheritedObjectType : 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
ObjectFlags : None
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : DOMAINGROUP
IsInherited : False
InheritanceFlags : ContainerInherit
PropagationFlags : None
```

I've been trying to replicate that ACL with System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule

Any help would be much appreciated

Tried:

```
$ace2 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $GroupSID, "CreateChild, DeleteChild", "Allow", "All", '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

$ace2 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $GroupSID, "CreateChild, DeleteChild", "Allow", "All", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"

$ace2 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $GroupSID, "CreateChild, DeleteChild", "Allow", "Descendents", '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

$ace2 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $GroupSID, "CreateChild, DeleteChild", '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', "Allow", "All", '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

$ace2 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $GroupSID, "CreateChild, DeleteChild", "Allow", "All", '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

$ace2 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule($GroupSID, "CreateChild, DeleteChild", "Allow", '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', "Descendents")
```

Got:

```
New-Object : Multiple ambiguous overloads found for "ActiveDirectoryAccessRule" and the argument count: "5".
    At line:1 char:9
    + $ace2 = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule ...
    +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

Comment: The constructor for `ActiveDirectoryAccessRule` is not being called correctly

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.activedirectoryaccessrule?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0

And: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/df3bfd33-c070-4a9c-be98-c4da6e591a0a/forum-faq-using-powershell-to-assign-permissions-on-active-directory-objects

Comment: a quite simpler way is to configure one OU as you expect it to be, then read then ACL with get-aCL and apply the wanted ACEs to the OUs you want with set-acl.  To access AD as a drive you only have to import the ad module, after that you can access it by ad:

Answer (score 0):

Your 5 string arguments don't match any overload signature for the rule constructor exactly, but *might* match 2 of them if the arguments were converted to the correct argument type.

Providing arguments of the correct type will allow PowerShell to pick the right one:

```
$ace2 = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule]::new(
  [System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]$GroupSID, 
  [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryRights]"CreateChild, DeleteChild",
  [System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType]::Allow, 
  [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectorySecurityInheritance]::All, 
  [guid]::Empty)
```